# How do I add a JavaMail replyTo in coldfusion?

Tags: java, coldfusion, jakarta-mail

Using JavaMail I would do something like the following:

```
...
Address address[] = ...;
Message.setReplyTo(address[]);
...
```

In ColdFusion, I've tried creating an array and adding an address to the array. I can't just add an address as the method "setReplyTo" takes an Java Address Array of addresses.

I've tried the following (in cfscript):

```
<cfscript>
...
REPLYTO = createObject("java", "javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress").init("testy@testy.com", "Joe Schmoe");
replyToArr = arrayNew(1);
arrayAppend(replyToArr,REPLYTO);
msg.setReplyTo(replyToArr);
...
<cfscript>
```

And also just:

```
<cfscript>
...
REPLYTO = createObject("java", "javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress").init("testy@testy.com", "Joe Schmoe");
msg.setReplyTo(REPLYTO);
...
<cfscript>
```

No bueno. Any suggestions?

Comment: Nevermind. I'm a big dummy. I was throwing an exception on another line.

It works just to create a coldfusion array, add addresses to the array and then set the replyTo.

    <cfscript>
    ...
    REPLYTO = createObject("java", "javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress").init("testy@testy.com", "Joe Schmoe");
    replyToArr = arrayNew(1);
    arrayAppend(replyToArr,REPLYTO);
    msg.setReplyTo(replyToArr);
    ...
    <cfscript>

Comment: Glad you solved it. You should post the code an answer and accept it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you don't mind me asking, why did you choose `JavaMail` over `CFMail`?

Comment: @Micah I'm using Amazon simple email service for email. They have a nice little java library, so it's easier to interface with that via javamail. (although I think now they have just plain ol smtp, you don't get robust exception info with that though.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind. I was throwing an exception on another line.

It works just to create a coldfusion array, add addresses to the array and then set the replyTo.

```
<cfscript>
...
REPLYTO = createObject("java", "javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress").init("testy@testy.com", "Joe Schmoe");
replyToArr = arrayNew(1);
arrayAppend(replyToArr,REPLYTO);
msg.setReplyTo(replyToArr);
...
<cfscript>
```